# Samsung Knox locked and possibly removed all the data stored inside it. Can I recover it?

Tags: samsung

I have been using Samsung knox for over 6 months now and a few days back, decided to change my older password. Did so and also changed the security pin. Now I have forgotten both password and the pin to the account. I entered wrong password 20 times in a period of 2 days. As a result my knox got deleted. Now if someone could help, I would like to know if I can recover my data of the account.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. Knox is meant to be secure, so short of taking the chip out of the phone and scanning it to get the fingerprint of fragments of info, you can't recover it.